# ¿Como compruebo si existe algún radioButton seleccionado o no dentro de un radioGroup?

Tags: java, android

```
if(nameEvent.equals("")||inithourEvent.equals("")||(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1)){
                    Dialogo.dismiss();
                    Log.i("WARNING","¡Existen campos vacios!");
```

Uso este método pero si selecciono uno de los rButton ignora las demas comprobaciones

Comment: Cómo que *si selecciono uno de los rButton ignora las demas comprobaciones*? El comportamiento *normal* de los RadioButton es precisamente que si seleccionas uno ya no puedes seleccionar otro... Para eso están los CheckBox

Comment: El error estaba en otra parte del código, la comprobación del if es erronea, la forma correcta sería nameEvent.getText().toString().isEmpty(), esto comprueba si el EditText está vacio, la comprobación anterior el error se mostraba al seleccionar o no uno de los rButton pero el metodo getCheckedRadioButtonId es correcto, este indica si algun rButton está seleccionado o no, gracias por responder

Comment: En realidad para que te sea más cómodo puedes usar `TextUtils.isEmpty(tuEditText)`